How to Evaluate $\int \frac{|x+5|-7}{|x+5|+|x+7|+7}\mathrm dx$ Using the $\text{sgn}$ Function?
I want to integrate $$\int \frac{|x+5|-7}{|x+5|+|x+7|+7}\mathrm dx$$
My approach:
$1)$ When $x+5>0,x+7>0$ then the integral will be $$\int\frac{x-2}{2x+19}\mathrm dx$$
Now, this is easy to integrate.
$2)$ When $x+5<0,x+7>0$ then the integral will become $$\int\frac{-x-12}{9}\mathrm dx$$
Now after this step, similarly it is easy to integrate.
$3)$ When $x+5<0, x+7<0$, then the integral will become $$\int\frac{-x-12}{-2x-5}\mathrm dx$$
Similarly, this is also easy to integrate.
But my doubt is that can't we integrate the above expression by the help of signum function that is $\text{sgn}(x+5), \text{sgn}(x+7)$?

Maybe you mean $x+5<0$, not $|x+5|<0$?

Yes correct @o.spectrum

Which is better among Wolfram Mathematica and Geogebra ?

Actually both are giving different results of the above integration.

For computational purposes I prefer Wolfram Mathematica, it is very powerful and precise in numerous mathematical operations.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: let $f(t):=\frac{|t+5|-7}{|t+5|+|t+7|+7}$. I recommend you evaluate $\int_{-7}^xf(t)dt$ for $x<-7$, $-7\le x<-5$ and $x\ge-5$. (You can start be rewriting $f$ without modulus signs in each of these regions.)

You can define this integral as a weighted sum of the integrals that you've written with weights being the Heaviside step functions. I.e. you will have three intervals with three respective integrals in the following fashion:
$$\int\frac{|x+5|-7}{|x+5|+|x+7|+7}dx=H(x+5)H(x+7)\int f_1(x) dx + H(x+7)(1-H(x+5))\int f_2(x) dx + (1-H(x+5))(1-H(x+7))\int f_3(x) dx$$
Where $f_1,\,f_2,\,f_3$ are the very functions you derived when opening the absolute values of $x+5$ and $x+7$. $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function (kinda like $\mathrm{sgn}$ just a bit different, since it zeroes if the argument is less than $0$).

The antiderivatives of $f_1$ and $f_3$, if naively written as $F_1(x) = \frac{1}{2}x+A\ln\left|x+\frac{19}{2}\right|$ and $F_3(x)=\frac{1}{2}x+B\ln\left|x+\frac{5}{2}\right|$ are not defined on the complete set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}.$ This does not change if you multiply with $0$. If you want to have something that is defined on $\mathbb{R},$ you have to use additional Heaviside step functions or similar functions inside the logarithm to get rid of the poles in the "uninteresting" intervals, too.

I can't understand that why $sgn$ function can't be used here ?

You can write the Heaviside step function in terms of the sign function, if you like.

How? Can u explain me?,@ReinhardMeier

$H(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\mathrm{sgn}(x)+1)$

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{|x+5|-7}{|x+5| + |x+7| + 7} \,\mathrm{d}t
    &= \int \begin{cases}
\frac{-(x+5)-7}{-(x+5) + -(x+7) + 7} &, x < -7 \\
\frac{-(x+5)-7}{-(x+5) + (x+7) + 7} &, -7 \leq x < -5 \\
\frac{(x+5)-7}{(x+5) + (x+7) + 7} &, -5 \leq x
\end{cases} \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
    &= \int \begin{cases}
\frac{-x-12}{-2x-5} &, x < -7 \\
\frac{-x-12}{9} &, -7 \leq x < -5 \\
\frac{x-2}{2x+19} &, -5 \leq x
\end{cases} \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
    &= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}(19 \ln(|2x+5|)+2x+5) + C_1  &, x < -7 \\
\frac{-1}{18}(x^2 - 24x) + C_2  &, -7 \leq x < -5 \\
\frac{-1}{4}(23 \ln(|2x+19|) -2x -19 + C_3  &, -5 \leq x
\end{cases}  \\
    &= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}(19 \ln(-2x-5)+2x+5) + C_1  &, x < -7 \\
\frac{-1}{18}(x^2 - 24x) + C_2  &, -7 \leq x < -5 \\
\frac{-1}{4}(23 \ln(2x+19) -2x -19 + C_3  &, -5 \leq x
\end{cases} \text{.}
\end{align*}
Now let's solve for $C_2$ and $C_3$ to ensure we get the continuous function we require.  (If the arguments to the logarithms could be zero on their intervals, we must allow that the antiderivative is discontinuous at such a zero -- having a constant of integration to the left of the zero and different constant of integration to the right.  Happily, that does not happen here.)
\begin{align*}
\left. \frac{1}{4}(19 \ln(-2x-5|)+2x+5) + C_1 \right|_{x=-7}
    &= \left. \frac{-1}{18}(x^2 - 24x) + C_2 \right|_{x=-7}  \text{, }\\
\frac{1}{4}(19\ln(9)-9) + C_1 
    &= \frac{119}{18} + C_2  \\
C_2 &= \frac{1}{36}(36 C_1 + 171 \ln(9) - 319)  \\
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\left. \frac{-1}{18}(x^2 - 24x) + C_2 \right|_{x=-5}
    &= \left. \frac{-1}{4}(23 \ln(2x+19) -2x -19 + C_3 \right|_{x=-5}
\frac{95}{18} + C_2  \\
    &= \frac{-1}{4}(23 \ln(9) - 9) + C_3  \\
C3 &= \frac{1}{36}(36 C_2 + 207 \ln(9) + 109)  \\
    &= \frac{1}{36}(36 C_1 + 378 \ln(9) - 210)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
So the resulting antiderivative is
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}(19 \ln(-2x-5)+2x+5) + C_1  &, x < -7 \\
\frac{-1}{18}(x^2 - 24x) + \frac{1}{36}(36 C_1 + 171 \ln(9) - 319)  &, -7 \leq x < -5 \\
\frac{-1}{4}(23 \ln(2x+19) -2x -19 + \frac{1}{36}(36 C_1 + 378 \ln(9) - 210)  &, -5 \leq x
\end{cases} \\
\qquad = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}(19 \ln(-2x-5)+2x+5) + C_1  &, x < -7 \\
\frac{-1}{36}(2x^2 - 48x - 36 C_1 - 171 \ln(9) + 319)  &, -7 \leq x < -5 \\
\frac{1}{12}(6x - 69 \ln(2x+19) + 12 C_1 + 126 \ln(9) - 13)  &, -5 \leq x
\end{cases} \text{.}
\end{align*}
We can try to force the appearance of "$|x+7|$" and/or "$|x+5|$" in these cases, but they don't naturally occur here.
